# How can I know if a pronoun sounds good?

Tags: pronouns

Often, native speakers tell me my use of a pronoun isn't wrong but it doesn't sound good or quite right. I don't have a native ear. How can I tell? For example, I was told that "ones" and "that" don't sound good. But why?

> Alternative medicines and treatments take time to work, whereas
> conventional **ones** are developed to work fast.

I was told better to use this version:

> Alternative medicines and treatments take time to work, whereas
> **conventional medical treatments** are developed to work fast.

Another example:

> The graph compares the number of store openings with **that** of closures
> in one country between 2011 and 2018.

I was told better to repeat "number":

> The graph compares the number of store openings with **the number** of closures
> in one country between 2011 and 2018.

Comment: *Ones* and *that* sound fine to me.  Unfortunately, I feel like this question might be too general to be answered, if the person did not say *why* they thought these words didn't seem right.

Comment: Thank you very much. In the first example, I was told better to use "conventional medical treatments" instead of "ones". In the second example, I was told better to repeat "number": the number of closures.

Comment: It sounds like you have better English than some of the people offering you advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, in my view, nothing at all wrong with the sentence:

> Alternative medicines and treatments take time to work, whereas conventional ones are developed to work fast.

Indeed, I incline to think it is better English than the suggested alternative:

> Alternative medicines and treatments take time to work, whereas conventional medical treatments are developed to work fast.

(Minor point not addressed in the question, a word such as "rapidly" or "quickly" might read better than "*fast*" in either sentence.)

In the case of the sentence:

> The graph compares the number of store openings with that of closures in one country between 2011 and 2018.

I think that the word "*that*" is sufficiently far from its referent "*number*" that a rewrite night be a good idea. One could repeat the word number, as suggested, or use a construction such as:

> The graph compares the number of store openings and closures in one country between 2011 and 2018.

This makes the parallelism between "*openings*" and "*closures*" clearer, and avoids the possible probl;em of a reader being confused about the referent of "*that*".

Comment: Thank you very much but I don't understand this version: The graph compares the number of store openings and closures in one country between 2011 and 2018. Why is the singular "number" used? I think you can only compare two numbers. Why isn't the plural "numbers" used?

Comment: @Learner110 Yes, one compares two numbers, or as here, two sets of numbers. In this form as is common, repeated parallel elements are left out: *The graph compares the number of store openings and [the number of] closures in one country.* One could use a plural form "*the number**s** of*" because multiple years are involved, but I preferred the singular because there is **one** number for openings (and one for closings) in **each** year.

Comment: Thank you very much.